# Show button when all EditTexts are filled out by user

Tags: android, button, android-edittext, kotlin

I have this login activity, when the user clicks on either Login or Register Button, different EditTexts appear. My question is how can i check if all EditTexts are filled out so the continueButton will be enabled?

(When Login is clicked, email and password must be filled, and when register is clicked, email, password and username must be filled)

[image: Login is clicked]
[image: Register is clicked]
ACTIVITY_LOGIN.XML

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/tableLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/yellow"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".LoginActivity">

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/welcomeTableRow"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="8pt">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/welcomeTextView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="@string/welcome_to"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="normal|bold" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/logoTableRow"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/welcomeLogoImageView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_span="2"
            android:contentDescription="@string/todo"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/logo_medium" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/loginInfoTableRow"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="12pt">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/infoEditText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:padding="6pt"
            android:text="@string/ask_to_register_or_login"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="18sp" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/loginOrRegisterTableRow"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="4pt"
        android:layout_marginEnd="40dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="40dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp">

        <Button
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
            android:id="@+id/chooseToLoginButton"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/login_screen_button_unclicked"
            android:onClick="chosenEvent"
            android:text="@string/login" />

        <Button
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
            android:id="@+id/chooseToRegisterButton"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/login_screen_button_unclicked"
            android:onClick="chosenEvent"
            android:text="@string/register" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/nameTableRow"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginEnd="12dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:padding="4pt"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:weightSum="1">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/nameTextView"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.3"
            android:paddingEnd="2pt"
            android:paddingStart="2pt"
            android:text="@string/name"
            android:textAlignment="textEnd"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/nameEditText"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.65"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="@string/name"
            android:inputType="textPersonName" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/emailTableRow"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginEnd="12dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:padding="4pt"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:weightSum="1">


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/emailTextView"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.3"
            android:paddingEnd="2pt"
            android:paddingStart="2pt"
            android:text="@string/email"
            android:textAlignment="textEnd"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/emailEditText"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.65"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="@string/email"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/passwordTableRow"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginEnd="12dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:padding="4pt"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:weightSum="1">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/passwordTextView"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.3"
            android:paddingEnd="2pt"
            android:paddingStart="2pt"
            android:text="@string/password"
            android:textAlignment="textEnd"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/passwordEditText"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.65"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="@string/password"
            android:inputType="textPassword" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/continueButtonTableRow"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="8pt"
        android:visibility="visible">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/continueButton"
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="80dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="80dp"
            android:background="@drawable/login_screen_button_unclicked"
            android:enabled="false"
            android:text="@string/continue_button"
            android:visibility="visible" />
    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```

LOGIN ACTIVITY:

```
import android.os.Bundle
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.view.View
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_login.*

LoginActivity:

class LoginActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login)
    }

    private fun unclickAllChooseButtons() {
        chooseToLoginButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.login_screen_button_unclicked)
        chooseToRegisterButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.login_screen_button_unclicked)
    }

    private fun showEmailRow() {
        emailTableRow.visibility = View.VISIBLE
    }

    private fun showNameRow() {
        nameTableRow.visibility = View.VISIBLE
    }

    private fun showPasswordRow() {
        passwordTableRow.visibility = View.VISIBLE
    }

    private fun hideAllRows() {
        emailTableRow.visibility = View.GONE
        passwordTableRow.visibility = View.GONE
        nameTableRow.visibility = View.GONE
    }

    fun chosenEvent(view: View) {
        when (view.id) {
            R.id.chooseToLoginButton -> {
                unclickAllChooseButtons()
                chooseToLoginButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.login_screen_button_clicked)
                hideAllRows()
                showEmailRow()
                showPasswordRow()
            }
            R.id.chooseToRegisterButton -> {
                unclickAllChooseButtons()
                chooseToRegisterButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.login_screen_button_clicked)
                hideAllRows()
                showNameRow()
                showEmailRow()
                showPasswordRow()
            }
            else -> {
                unclickAllChooseButtons()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Serioulsy, what is stopping you? What had you tried so far?

Comment: @Selvin OP probably doesn't know how to start because real-time validations based on text changes are not intuitive. However, is part of the rules adding coded attempts.

Comment: i tried all the stuff with isEmpty(), == "", == null, neither worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a hard one because what you need to do is to enable the button in real-time. So you have to listen each `EditText` and once a condition is met on the written text then you should set the button as enabled. There is another complexity here, which it is: what happened if the user goes back and then try to delete some text. There are 2 ways to solve this last issue, the first is to save a state of each EditText and the second is to also validate the data to be sent.

```
    //You have to set initial state as false representing conditione haven'met
    //Otherwise when you try to get the tag is gonna be null
    boolean initialValidity = false;
    emailEt.setTag(initialValidity);
    passEt.setTag(initialValidity);
    emailEt.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
        String email = emailEt.getText().toString();
        //You can improve this condition
        if (email.trim().length() > 0 && email.contains("@") && email.contains(".")) {
            emailEt.setTag(true);
            if ((boolean) passEt.getTag()) {
               sendButton.setEnabled(true); 
            }
        } else {
            emailEt.setTag(false);
            sendButton.setEnabled(false);
        }
    }
});
passEt.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
        String password = passEt.getText().toString();
        //You can improve this condition
        if (!password.contains(" ") && password.length() > 6) {
            passEt.setTag(true);
            if ((boolean) emailEt.getTag()) {
                sendButton.setEnabled(true);
            }
        } else {
            passEt.setTag(false);
            sendButton.setEnabled(false);
        }
    }
});
sendButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        String email = emailEt.getText().toString();
        String password = passEt.getText().toString();
        //TODO add validation to send the data
        //TODO send the data
    }
});
```

What we are doing here is listening to both `EditText` and while the user is writting we check if the conditions are met. Both `EditText` while checking their own condition and also the other condition. This crossed checking allow us to enable or disable the `Button` if any `EditText` breaks the clauses in the conditions. Each `EditText` can know if the other has met the needed conditions by checking the tag which is a boolean representing if the conditions are met or not. I'm using `enabled` as an example, you could hide using `setVisibility()`

Comment: i will have to try this!

Comment: Thank you very much, this was exactly what i was searching for!

Answer (score 0):

This is all the help you can get, cause you didn't include any code of yours. Also, my code is in Java, you should get the idea. 

`if(!edittext1.equals("") && !edittext2.equals("")){
       // enable button
 }`

Answer (score 0):

You must have different methods to validate that your forms are full, and finish with these validations:

```
                public boolean validatePassword(String password){if(!password.equals("")){
                        if(password.length() == 6){ //Valid if the password is of certain sizes

                            this.password = password;
                            return true;
                        }
                        else {
                            Toast.makeText(this, "Length invalid", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            return false;
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        Toast.makeText(this, "Please enter your password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        return false;
                    }
                }}
```

Method for each form.

You get the form data in the following way:

String pass = youreditText.getText().toString();

finally:

```
                    if(validatePassword(password)){ if(validateOtherForm(text){
                            //What you want to do
                        }}
```